# Run program installed on another computer over the network

Tags: networking, remote-execution

I have some software installed on my desktop but it's too big to install on my laptops SSD. What is the best way to use this software on my laptop over my home network?

Comment: Which ways have you tried already?  What OSs are in question?  Have you tried simply running the executable from the laptop (via a shared folder)?

Comment: the laptop is windows 7 and the desktop is windows 10, no i have not tried that but i will tonight.

Comment: If it's something that's not too graphics heavy you could use remote desktop to get to your desktop's interface on your laptop. Generally, unless it's a trivial standalone application, I would avoid trying to install/run applications on network storage... unless the storage device and the network connected to it are really fast.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have a mounted drive letter.
2. When the program asks you where to install it, click **Change** or whatever its called, and specify a path on the mounted drive.

All the files will be on the NAS, and the necessary registry entries will be on your computer.  Most programs, that are not portable version, fail to operate without there registry entries.